# Tweaking axis of 3D graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, color, axis

I have this graph, where the axis "n" varies between 0 and 200. However, since the "A/h" axis begins at 0, it looks at first glance that "n" is varying between 0 and 2000.

How can I erase the 0 in the "A/h" axis?

Additionally, is it possible so that the 0 in the "P" axis matches the 0 in the "n" axis and is not hovering a little bit?

Finally, I do not want color in the graph, would it be possible to have a grey scale in the colorbar and graph?

Thanks in advance.

(I use the package siunitx in my document)

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar, xlabel={n},ylabel={A\textsubscript{l}/h\textsubscript{l} [\si{\milli\metre}]},zlabel={P [\si{\watt}]}]
        \addplot3
            [surf,
            shader=interp,
            samples=10,
            domain=0:200,y domain=0:0.0001]
        {30.03530*x*y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: you should find all you need here http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html